# Need to capture activity of the UploadArchive and publish Gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, publish

I have a scenario where I need to capture below details in the init.gradle file.

Can we get all the activity of task ?

the Inputs params for UploadArchive and publish task, which repo is the artifact getting uploaded, all the GAV details …as POM can be customize within uploadArchive task.

We have applications running v3.5 to v6.3 versions of Gradle.

### Can you please assist

Hi @PrasadU

Can we determine which deployment url, uploadArchive task will pick at runtime.

```
uploadArchive {
    repositories {
       mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: ReleaseURL) {
                authentication(userName: Username, password: Password)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: SnapshotURL ) {
                authentication(userName: Username, password: Password)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understood the problem. I guess you can set parameter like `isrelease=false` in the `settings.gradle` file(one step above in the .gradle location where you place the init.grdle file) and you can set deployment repository like `if(${isrlease}"){ repository(...){...}}`

Comment: @JMadushan ...We dont want to restrict or enforce what should be the repository URL Instead we need to capture the repository URL in the init.gradle when the developer runs uploadArchive task on our servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task to list the same be made as below

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'abc.xyz'
            artifactId = 'overr-name'
            version = '1.1-OV'

            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("$buildDir/repos/releases")
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("$buildDir/repos/snaps")
        }
    }
}

task printML() {
    doLast {
        tasks.findAll {task ->
            if (task.name.matches("publish.*PublicationToMavenLocal")) {
                def publication = task.publicationInternal
                println("Local => $publication.artifactId $publication.groupId $publication.version")
            }
            if (task.name.matches("publish.*PublicationTo.*Repository")) {
                def publication = task.publicationInternal
                println("Remote => $publication.artifactId $publication.groupId $publication.version  $task.repository.url")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
> Task :printML
Remote => overr-name abc.xyz 1.1-OV  file:/Users/projects/Store/combined-samples/build/repos/snaps
Local => overr-name abc.xyz 1.1-OV
Remote => overr-name abc.xyz 1.1-OV  file:/Users/projects/Store/combined-samples/build/repos/releases
```

Comment: This is what I wanted for publish task. Similarly Let me try for UploadArchive task as well. Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me on UploadArchive task to get respository url at runtime

Comment: and artifact name, the issue is when you have rootproject name and basename are different. Artifact is will upload with basename which is defined in jar task…
```
project.archivesBaseName
project.name
```
Both give the same result, but baseName set in jar task is different.

Comment: I have a question on init.gradle. can you please assist.://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878832/gradle-init-gradle-is-repeat-executing-common-task-defined-in-allprojects-bloc#comment114708419_64878832