# Failing to run plugin from init.gradle

Tags: gradle

How to get plugin working from init.gradle?

Thanks,

H

```
$ cat ~/.gradle/init.gradle
allprojects{

buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'io.openliberty.tools:liberty-gradle-plugin:3.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'liberty'
}
```

$ gradle libertydev
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\hanym.gradle\init.gradle' line: 11

What went wrong:
Plugin with id 'liberty' not found.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Comment: Next time, please link to any cross-posts you make so we don't waste time answering the same question multiple times: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.gradle/issues/493

Comment: @bjørn-vester ..Can you please suggest on [How to determine the deployment url, uploadArchive task will pick at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838908/need-to-capture-activity-of-the-uploadarchive-and-publish-gradle-tasks)

For uploadArchive task, based on artifact version or release type . It can pick SnapshotURL or ReleaseURL. how to get the deployment URL at runtime. I want to read that url in init.gradle ? Please suggest.